# Get list of reserved words from within a Go program

Tags: go, code-generation

I am writing my first golang generator and want to make sure that some strings are not reserved keywords.
Should I copy the keywords from the spec to check against or does anyone know a better way?

Comment: The usual method is to just try and parse the generated source. The keywords are all handled by the tokenizer in the "go/token" package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `IsKeyword` method from the [`go/token`](https://godoc.org/go/token#Lookup) package. For instance:

```
token.Lookup("hello").IsKeyword() // false
token.Lookup("func").IsKeyword()  // true
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/E5Yux3Z_PO)